# CheckIncludeFileCXX does not find header

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to use the `CheckIncludeFileCXX` module to verify `<gsl/gsl>` is present in the system. [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) exists at `/usr/local/include/gsl/gsl` but generation fails at `"GSL not found"`

```
project(cpp-binaries)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX("gsl/gsl" GSL_LIBRARY)

if(NOT GSL_LIBRARY)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "GSL not found")
endif(NOT GSL_LIBRARY)

add_executable(
    cpp-binaries
    "main.cpp"
)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `GSL`, but are you sure that the header doesn't have a `.h` at the end? Otherwise don't use the compiler to find the header, use CMake modules (in your case [`FindGSL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGSL.html)) or [`find_file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_file.html) command. Or try to first `set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES "/usr/local/include")`.

Comment: [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) is a header-only library and there is no .h. It also will not work after setting `CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I looked more into `CheckIncludeFileCXX` and you basically have to specify something with `CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES` or else it doesn't know where to search. To give it something, it quietly searches for the include with `find_path` but still errors out if nothing is found.

```
project(gsl_t)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

find_path(
    gsl_location
    gsl
    HINTS ENV GSLDIR
)

if(gsl_location)
    get_filename_component(gsl_include_dir ${gsl_location} DIRECTORY)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${gsl_include_dir})
endif(gsl_location)

include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH})
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX("gsl/gsl" gsl_found)

if(NOT gsl_found)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "GSL not found. \
                        Try setting the GSLDIR environment variable")
endif(NOT gsl_found)

add_executable(
    gsl_t
    "main.cpp"
)
```